# How to setup validation for my knockout observables, that i created using Mappings plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

have been trying to set up validation like (required, min length, max lenght etc) for the properties on my knockout observables. I created my observables using Mapping plugin. I found the followign links, but could someone help me, figure out which is the right way to go, to set up validation. Here are the links that i was looking at.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

I put my code in jsfiddle, Currently it is not running, since it is complaining about knockout files. But Thought some one can see my code here http://jsfiddle.net/wQfuM/13/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get your jsfiddle to work. but here's a simple way to do it. You can control the creation of the observables using the mapping plugins mapping options object.

```
var json = {
    someValue: "foo"
};

var viewModel = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
        someValue: {
            create: function(options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ minLength: 10 });
            }
        }
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(json));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/b3UrF/1/

Hope this helps.